# JQuery -ui plugin not working in Grail

Tags: grails-plugin

I m using Grails 1.3.2 along with jquery-1.4.2.1. For tab & dialog component i install the plugin jquery-ui 1.8.2. I follow the instraction given at http://www.grails.org/plugin/jquery-ui. But i m unable to show the jquery tab in my project.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this two pages can help you:

http://www.pubbs.net/201006/grails/37636-grails-user-grails-ui-plugin-info-to-get-it-working.html

That one explains it really well, is a little out dated but it should take just a little of understanding to figure it out.

I you wanna get more technical you can use this one, but with the link above should be more than fine.

http://www.pubbs.net/201006/grails/37609-grails-user-yeah-jqueryui-plugin-wont-work.html

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to add following line for plugin.

plugins {

```
    runtime ":jquery:1.8.3"

compile ":jquery-ui:1.8.24"
}
```

1. Add the following line on which gsp page you use Jquery UI.

< head>

```
 < g:javascript library="jquery" />

 < r:require modules="jquery-ui"/>

 < r:script>

    $(document).ready(function() {
           your code...
    });
 < /r:script>
```

< /head>